# Unicode char appears as ?? on debian

Tags: java, debian, gson

I'm parsing the JSON received from a Minecraft server's ping request. The code works fine on Windows and gives the following output:

```
§4§l> §f§l> §4§l> §7-=[ §5§lMythCraft §6§lNetwork §7]=- §4§l> §f§l> §4§l> §7-=[ §b§lFaction 1 Has Reset §e➸ §c§lFresh Map! §7]=-
```

However, on my Debian VPS the following is outputted instead:

```
??4??l> ??f??l> ??4??l> ??7-=[ ??5??lMythCraft ??6??lNetwork ??7]=- ??4??l> ??f??l> ??4??l> ??7-=[ ??b??lFaction 1 Has Reset ??e??? ??c??lFresh Map! ??7]=-
```

I would assume that this is an encoding issue. Am I correct? How can I fix it?

The ping code is [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9702977/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The default charmap on my machine wasn't UTF-8, so it couldn't process the characters correctly, and replaced with with a `?` instead.

To fix it, I changed the definition of the String `json` to be this:

```
String json = new String(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

That way the returned String is processed in UTF-8 instead of the default encoding.

Comment: Just as a reminder, when the option is available, accept your answer.